# SAS warning: complete separation of data points. The maximum likelihood estimate does not exist

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, proc

I did loggistic regression in SAS using the database shown below but I got several warnings. I tried to identify the outliers and exclude them then test for multicolinearity but still I am getting warnings.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
**********************************;
************** database **********;
***********************************;
data D_BP;
 input BP Age Weight BSA Dur Pulse Stress;
 datalines;
0 47 85.4  1.75  5.1  63 33
0 51 89.4  1.89  7    72 95
0 47 90.9  1.9   6.2  66 8
0 49 89.2  1.83  7.1  69 62
0 48 92.7  2.07  5.6  64 35
0 47 94.4  2.07  5.3  74 90
0 50 95    2.05  10.2 68 47
0 45 87.1  1.92  5.6  67 80
0 46 94.5  1.98  7.4  69 95
0 46 87    1.87  3.6  62 18
0 46 94.5  1.9   4.3  70 12
0 48 90.5  1.88  9    71 99
1 49 94.2  2.1   3.8  70 14
1 49 95.3  1.98  8.2  72 10
1 50 94.7  2.01  5.8  73 99
1 48 99.5  2.25  9.3  71 10
1 49 99.8  2.25  2.5  69 42
1 49 94.1  1.98  5.6  71 21
1 52 101.3 2.19  10   76 98
1 56 95.7  2.09  7    75 99
;
run;
****** do logistic regression **********;
Proc logistic data=work.D_bp;
Model BP=Age Weight BSA Dur Pulse Stress;
Run; 

**** identify outlier *********;
proc reg data=work.D_bp plots(only
label)=(RStudentByLeverage CooksD);
model BP=Age Weight BSA Dur Pulse Stress ;
run;

**** After removing outliers ==> assess multicollinearity*********;
**** assessing multicollinearity by 2 ways *********;
proc corr data=work.D_bp ;
Var Age Weight BSA Dur Pulse Stress;
run;

proc reg data=work.D_bp plots;
Model BP=Age Weight BSA Dur Pulse Stress/Collin vif tol;
run;

****** repeat logistic regression after excluding weight **********;
Proc logistic data=work.D_bp;
Model BP=Age BSA Dur Pulse Stress;
Run;
```

> WARNING: There is a complete separation of data points. The maximum likelihood estimate does
> not exist.
> WARNING: The LOGISTIC procedure continues in spite of the above warning. Results shown are
> based on the last maximum likelihood iteration. Validity of the model fit is
> questionable.

Comment: You have not enough data for such number of predictors. Try FIRTH option in model like: **Model BP=Age Weight BSA Dur Pulse Stress / firth** and look SAS documentation for this solution.

Comment: @crow16384 Thx for your precious input. It works after excluding many of those independent predictors esp weight. I also tried your code and it works. Appreciate your advice. Upvoted!